# Trying to reduce GC collections

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr

Can someone please tell me whether AddB below will result in less CLR allocations than AddA? I've examined disassembly and it looks to be the case but I'd like confirmation from the **Experts** please. Can someone **Exchange** this information with me please?

Cheers,
Charlie.

---

```
namespace A
{
    struct Vec2
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;

        public Vec2 AddA(Vec2 other)
        {
            Vec2 v = new Vec2(); // Reference variable
            v.x = x + other.x;
            v.y = y + other.y;
            return v;
        }

        public Vec2 AddB(Vec2 other)
        {
            Vec2 v;              // Value variable
            v.x = x + other.x;
            v.y = y + other.y;
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Vec2 is a `struct` in both examples, by using `Vec2 v = new Vec2();` you are **not** creating a reference to your struct, you are simply creating a new struct on your stack. If you don't use the `new` keyword, your struct is nevertheless created on the stack and you can initialize each field separately.

In that case, using the `new` keyword for a struct does't make much sense if your constructor doesn't accept some meaningful parameters to initialize the data in a single line.

If the first method uses a `class` instead of a `struct`, then it does create an object for GC to collect, unlike the second method. Since v in `AddB` is allocated on the stack, it is not collected, the stack is simply popped when your method is finished.

Comment: +1, but note that if Vec2 is a class then AddB simply won't work

Comment: Note: If Vec2 would be a class, the code in AddB doesn't work at all. You have to create an instance of a class to use it.

Comment: Yeah, and also make sure that the GC is works on a highly optimized mechanism. Though you can control the GC behavior somehow using the GC class-which is a handle on the GC for your process, It's very discouraged to do it. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx

Comment: thanks for this, very clear - there are no reference or value variables, just reference and value types. Got it.

Answer (score 3):

There's no guarantee for anything. Value items are not necessarily stored in the heap.

See [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) by Eric Lippert, and the following [second part](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx).

Comment: Good link. However: while this *is* an implementation detail, the OP asked specifically for such details. Since these are not likely to change in the next few years, assumptions about the local variable being allocated on the stack can be relied on.

Comment: Although it's an implementation detail, the CLR cannot choose to allocate the struct as a GC tracked reference, so it will not add memory pressure on the GC anyway.

Comment: An excellent read, to be sure, although it's worth bearing in mind that the CLR runs on some platforms with a much less friendly garbage collector than the Windows implementation. XNA Game Studio (which is awesome, and based on C# and managed DirectX) runs on both Xbox and Windows, and garbage collects quite differently on the 2 platforms which can make a big difference to your frame rate.

Answer (score 3):

The code in your AddA method simply does the same as:

```
public Vec2 AddA(Vec2 other) {
   Vec2 v;
   v.x = 0;
   v.y = 0;
   v.x = x + other.x;
   v.y = y + other.y;
   return v;
}
```

The parameterless constructor of a struct returns the default value for the struct, which is a value where all the members are zeroed out. The value is just returned by the call to the constructor, it's never allocated on the heap.

Also, a mutable struct is generally a bad idea. I would implement it like:

```
struct Vec2 {

    public float X { get; private set; }
    public float Y { get; private set; }

    public Vec2(float x, float y) {
       X = x;
       Y = y;
    }

    public Vec2 Add(Vec2 other) {
       return new Vec2(X + other.X, Y + other.Y);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `AddA` and `AddB` do not differ in their memory behaviour, both will be allocated on the stack. What **does** make a difference is that `AddB` does not call the default constructor for the type and thereby leaves the fields of the `Vec2` uninitialized, whereas `AddA` will zero them out first.

Having said that I'd imagine that the performance hit of zeroing the contents is probably not measurable (if the JIT compiler doesn't even remove it altogether anyway).

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers:

**Firstly**, the code can be improved by using an appropriate constructor and thus omitting the tedious assignments. This isn't really optional: it *should* be done. Additionally, it would be *good* to implement such a structure as an immutable type, i.e. making the fields `readonly` so chances to it aren't at all possible: thus, you would implement pure value semantics.

**Secondly**, concerning the question of stack vs. heap allocation: I wouldn't bother too much here anyway: the kind of GC used in .NET is specialized to handle lots of such small allocations: your code would be the optimal scenario as far as the .NET GC is concerned. Don't try to avoid it.